# How to have different backgrounds on different sides of a <hr> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to have different backgrounds on different sides of a hr tag.

Example (where '---' represents the hr tag output) -

```
background1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
background2
```

How to achieve this **without using table**?

Comment: Use divs. Each with different backgrounds.

Comment: @Corey>> can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style='background-color: blue'>Some stuff</div>

<hr>

<div style='background-color: red'>Some other stuff</div>
```

Just as easy as that!
[Background CSS specifications](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3868361)

Now, you will probably be wondering about the margins... Just set the `hr` margin to zero!
Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UULf/)

Comment: Could please the two downvoters explain the reason? I certainly don't see why this should be wrong, since it answers the question asked.

Comment: very short and very well explained with JSFiddle!

Answer (score 0):

you could make some css and do it like this

```
    p.separator {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

But in honesty it's hard to tell what you want without any code.

Comment: That's not a bad start at all. I think the user was looking to do it with an `hr`, though (simple change), and they probably do want it to have height to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a div before and after. Put the background color on these div.

In these div, you just have to set a width style.

If you want some example:

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:20px; height:20px">
</div>
<hr style="width:200px;" />
<div style="background-color:blue; width:20px; height:20px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `<div>`s for this, there is no need for a `<hr>` as it can be done with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top">example</div>
<div>example</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
div.top {
    background: red;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p9nP/)**